# Is it possible to remove 'similar' items from a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of DateTime items, and I'd like to remove any that are within 2 minutes of each other (the first one encountered should remain).  Could someone tell me how I could achieve this using LINQ?  Would an extension method be necessary?

To clarify, some sample data:

00:00:00 00:01:30 00:02:30 00:05:00

Should return:

00:00:00 00:05:00

Comment: what do you mean by `within 2 minutes of each other`?

Comment: Delete all that are *withing 2 minutes of each other* or leave the first/last one? Any sample input?

Comment: Sorry I should have made that clearer.  I'd like the first one to remain.  I don't have any sample input yet, I'm just trying to work out a good way to tackle the problem.

Comment: who favorited this question!?!?! o_O

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?  Also, what happens when you have 8:00:00 AM, 8:01:30 AM, and 8:02:30 AM?

Comment: @Peter All of those dates are with 2 minutes of at least one other, so none would be included.

Comment: But 8:00:00 AM isn't within 2 minutes of 8:02:30 AM ... if 8:01:30 AM is being removed, then shouldn't 8:02:30 AM stay?

Comment: @Peter see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536211/linq-is-it-possible-to-remove-similar-items-from-a-collection/18536297#comment27262462_18536297)

Comment: Please make sure to look at my answer.

Comment: @TimothyShields See my comments, that seems to be implementing a slightly different algorithm than what the requirements state.  You seem to have the same interpretation as Peter.

Comment: The question is not clear.  Fix the question and include some sample data and desired output or it will continue to be down voted.

Comment: @Servy True - another valid interpretation is what you did. I think the question is worded pretty poorly...

Comment: @TimothyShields Voting to close as unclear and deleting my answer until the OP clarifies.  Reading it over a few more times there are just too many possible interpretations.

Comment: It's clear to me. He asks for the first one to be retained. Subsequent items within 2 minutes are to be removed.

Comment: @Servy If the requirements aren't clear and/or don't make sense, it's important to get clarification before starting work.

Comment: @Peter Sure.  I thought it was pretty clear the first time I read through it, but the OP's edit was what actually made it *less* clear.  Without that edit I'd say that the wording makes it clear enough that your interpretation isn't right.  With the edit it seems that it's still not technically right, but that it may be what the OP intended to write, which is what makes it unclear.  That said, I also only threw 30 seconds into my answer; not a huge investment.

Comment: Honestly I don't get your example.  Why 2.30 disappears? because it's in 2 mins range from 1.30? then the chain 0:0 - 1:30 - 3:0 - 5:0 should just return 0:0?

Comment: @Save The logic here is to make groups such that all of those groups contain dates within the threshold of each other, then take the first item from the group.  In your example you would be correct, it would only return 0:0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the idea here is to group the items first.  While going through the items in the list (that's sorted) if the current item is within the threshold of the previous item it should go into the same group, if not, it should start its own group.

We can create a `GroupWhile` function that takes a function which is given the previous and current items, and determines if they should be grouped together.  We sort the data, group given the provided condition, and then take the first item in each group.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> LoneDates(
    IEnumerable<DateTime> dates, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return dates.OrderBy(x => x)
        .GroupWhile((previous, current) => current - previous <= threshold)
        .Select(group => group.First());
}
```

As for implementing `GroupWhile`, it can be done like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                list.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
            }

            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Reading through this it puts the first item in its own group, then it goes through each other item in the sequence; if the given function says that it should be added to the current group it is, if not the current group is sent to the output sequence and a new group is created.

Using your sample input:

```
var data = new List<DateTime>()
{
    DateTime.Today,
    DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(1.5),
    DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(2.5),
    DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(5),
};

var query = LoneDates(data, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", query));
```

results in:

> 8/30/2013 12:00:00 AM
>
> 8/30/2013 12:05:00 AM

which is the expected output.

Comment: If threshold is 120 seconds, and I have a bunch of times that are 90 seconds apart, it will only return the first time.

Answer (score 0):

## Query

This query will get you a time T if and only if there is not a directly preceding time that is less than 2 seconds before.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> times = ...;

var query = times
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Throttle((x, y) => y.Subtract(x) <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

## Helper

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Throttle(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> collapse)
{
    var first = true;
    var prev = default(T);
    foreach (var curr in source)
    {
        if (first || !collapse(prev, curr))
        {
            yield return curr;
            first = false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the same input the OP edited in, this fails to properly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Non Linq answer, seems to be straight forward.

```
 private List<DateTime> RemoveItems(List<DateTime> times)
        {
            var newtimes = new List<DateTime>();

            var previoustime = new DateTime();

            var firsttime = times[0];

            newtimes.Add(firsttime);

            foreach (var time in times)
            {
                if (firsttime == time)
                {
                    previoustime = time;
                    continue;
                }

                if ((time - previoustime) > new TimeSpan(0,0,1,30))
                {
                    newtimes.Add(time);
                }

                previoustime = time;
            }

            return newtimes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I tested and it seems to work:

```
//build the data to test
List<DateTime> data = new List<DateTime>();
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   data.Add(new DateTime(2013, 12, 22, 12, rand.Next(50),0));
}
//----------
DateTime fix = DateTime.Now;
int j = 0;
var result = data.OrderBy(x => x)
                         .Select((x,i)=>new{x,i})
                         .GroupBy(x=> {
                             if(x.i == 0) fix = x.x;
                             else if ((x.x - fix).TotalMinutes >= 2)
                             {
                                 fix = x.x;
                                 j++;
                             }
                             return j;
                            }, e=>e.x, (key,e)=>e.First());
```